# Deploying Flask application on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

This is my first web app I've ever developed, so even though I thoroughly searched everything I could for the Google App Engine, I'm afraid that my terminology and Google fu simply isn't good enough for what I need.
When I open up my terminal and type "python main.py", I can see that it works correctly on localhost.
Now I am trying to host this application on the Google App Engine. I have spent hours watching Youtube tutorials and following setup guides, trying to emulate their file structure and file contents. Whenever I deploy my app, I get the "500- Server Error: The server encountered an error and could not complete your request."

Here is my code: https://github.com/csherrod5/csherrod5.github.io
Here is an example of the types of guides I've been following: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-web-app-using-pythons-flask-and-google-app-engine-52b1bb82b221
I'm hoping someone is kind enough to help me diagnose my problem.
Thank you to everyone who stops by

Comment: App engine has good logging. If you go to the app engine console -> logging you should be able to see the stacktrace which will tell you why it's crashing.

Comment: Pro-tip: change your secret keys immediately since it appears you uploaded them.  In the future, I'd suggest keeping them in a configuration file that doesn't go up with your source control and gets loaded at runtime

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 thank you for the tip, I will take action accordingly.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Can you elaborate on this? I am on Google Cloud's Logging Page, I selected my project, but it just gives me an infinite loading circle

Comment: Update, all I see in my console logs are 4 logs that all look like this: [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?_ga=2.167798113.-134905901.1542665677&project=garbage-ro&folder=&organizationId=&minLogLevel=0&expandAll=false&timestamp=2018-11-20T05:52:04.713000000Z&customFacets=&limitCustomFacetWidth=true&dateRangeStart=2018-11-20T04:52:04.964Z&dateRangeEnd=2018-11-20T05:52:04.964Z&interval=PT1H&resource=gae_app&scrollTimestamp=2018-11-20T05:47:27.315000000Z)

Comment: `resource.type="gae_app"
resource.labels.project_id="garbage-ro"
resource.labels.module_id="default"
timestamp="2018-11-20T05:47:27.315000000Z"
insertId="-atk4pld9uf6"`

Comment: Just to emphasise, you should change the key and remove it from your GitHub repo as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

There's no lib folder in your application directory, so App Engine won't have any of the third party libraries you're trying to import.

You've correctly added the appengine_config.py file needed to vendorise third-party libraries, but you need to [add the libraries you want to use to a 'lib' folder in your application directory](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library).

Some of the libraries you want to use are built into the runtime, you just have to [add them to your app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#using_a_built-in_third-party_library_bundled_with_the_runtime) to use them.